# No-Code automatic solution for adding Salescloud Contacts to Marketingcloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect

Requirements:

1. The user creates a new Account + Contact record in Salescloud
2. This contact needs to be somehow transferred to Marketing cloud
3. Then the contact should receive a DoubleOptin email with a link. When the contact clicks the link, we need to store in the Marketingcloud the timestamp/datetime when the contact clicked the link.
4. After confirming the email, the contact should be eligable to receive newsletters

As far as I know there are the following ways to transfer a contact from Salescloud to Marketingcloud:

1. Call the Marketingcloud API to add the contact and assign it to a subscription list. The DoubleOptin email can be sent automatically
2. Use DataExtensions/Journeys to constantly lookup and transfer new records from Salescloud to Marketingcloud. The problem here is that there is no way to automatically send a DoublOptin email

When I go with (1), I'd need to code the API call.
When I go with (2), I'd need to code the DoubleOptin Landing Page

What am I missing? Is there no standard way to simply move a Contact from Salescloud to Marketingcloud and have an DoubleOptin email delivered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the connector and synchronised data extension to bring in new contact data and have the double optin email as part of a journey. I would however recommend triggered emails which will involve some coding on your side.

Comment: Thanks. In the Journey, I can send a "double optin email" as a normal email, but such an email needs to contain a link that when it is clicked by the user, the user's record in the Marketing Cloud needs to store that the user opted in - and we need to store also the timestamp when the user opted in. I don't see a no-code solution for this using the Journey Buider, right?